# Is there a warning for string literal to bool conversion in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

In a quite large code base, I found the following construct (rewritten snippet) in a cpp file

```
int main()
{
    bool b;
    //... some code ...;
    b = "False"
}
```

This is completely legal code, but clearly not intentional. It is easily fixed, but it has been present since 2014 without anyone noticing, so it is obviously not easy to spot.

Is it possible to make gcc warn about this?

Comment: Neither g++7 nor clang++5 warn with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`. Wow.

Comment: fyi: `bool b{"False"};` also compiles.  But `char const pc[] = "false"; bool b{pc};` gives a warning : _"warning: the address of 'pc' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]"_

Comment: Looking through [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) I can't find anything.

Comment: Such kind of bugs can be found by static analyzers. For example, PVS-Studio has this [diagnostic](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V601/).

Comment: I just found this after finding a bug in my code that read something like... `if (str == "one" || str == "two" || "three" || str == "four")` ... it was a code that was edited many times and somehow the `str ==` part was lost in when checking for `"three"`. I just added this warning to all my builds :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither **g++ 7** nor **clang++ 5** warn with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.

Clang has a warning called `-Wstring-conversion` that will catch the mistake, but gcc doesn't have it. I briefly looked through [the gcc warning documentation page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and didn't find anything that would catch the mistake.

[image]

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Sq6CQXwtV8IE4j4R)

---

I've filed a report for a feature suggestion on the gcc bug tracker: [**#80151**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80151).